# Convergence in probability implies convergence of some average

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

In a homework exercise we are given a probability space $(F,\Omega, \mathbb{P})$, a sequence of random variables $X_1, X_2, ... $ and a random variable $X$. If we construct the set $ N_n :=$ {$k\leq n: |X_k - X| > \epsilon $} we are tasked to show that if $X_n \rightarrow X$ a.s. then $\frac{1}{n}N_n \rightarrow 0$ a.s. This was pretty straight forward using techniques we learned in class. Next we are tasked to show that if we only require $X_n \rightarrow X$ in probability then we also have that $\frac{1}{n}N_n \rightarrow 0$ in probability. Here I get stuck, I get nowhere by applying the definition of convergence in probability or utilizing techniques we learned in class (i.e. trying to use Markov inequality). How should I approach this exercise?

Comment: If you already have the result for almost sure convergence, then you can prove the case of convergence in probability by "soft technique", i.e. there is a characterisation $Y_n \to Y$ in probability, if and only if, from every subsequence $(n_k)_k$ we can find further sub-subsequence $(n_{k_m})_m$ such that $Y_{n_{k_m}} \to Y$ almost surely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{|N_n|}{n} =\frac{1_{|X_1 - X|>\epsilon} + ... + 1_{|X_n - X| > \epsilon}}{n}.$$
So $$P(|N_n|/n > \epsilon) = P\left(\frac{1_{|X_1 - X|>\epsilon} + ... + 1_{|X_n - X| > \epsilon}}{n} > \epsilon\right) \leq \frac{E({1_{|X_1 - X|>\epsilon} + ... + 1_{|X_n - X| > \epsilon}})}{n\epsilon}.$$

Comment: I fail to see how this answers the question, though.

Comment: The RHS is equal to $\tfrac{1}{\epsilon} \overline{p_n}$ where $\overline{p_n} = \tfrac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n p_k$, where $p_k =  P(|X_k - X| > \epsilon)$. Since $p_k \to 0$,  $\overline{p_n} \to 0 $ by Cesaro's lemma.

Comment: OP can finish it from here...

Comment: The rewriting of the set using indicator functions was just the technique I needed to see. Thanks!